# How to get Checked Values from Facets-CheckBox Group?

Tags: checkbox, oracle-apex, facet, checked

I'm using ORACLE APEX "Sample Maps" example on the "120 - Airports Faceted Search" page.
I need to get the checked options from Facet "P120_STATE" (it's a checkbox group) and put this checked values in a Text Item called "CHECKED_STATES".
I don't know how to get the checked values in this facet checkbox group.
I need to get these checked values to use in another SQL command, for example:

`select CITIES.ID as ID, CITIES.NAME as NAME, CITIES.STATE_CODE as STATE_CODE from CITIES CITIES where STATE_CODE IN ( :CHECKED_STATES )`

Answer (score 0):

So the way APEX stores the values selected in the checkbox group behind the scenes is it creates a hidden input field and you can reference it using the value you gave under the Faceted Search's *Identification*.

**What's Inside P120_STATE?**

Inside the *Page Item* `P120_STATE`, your values will be a *colon-delimited string*. If your checkbox options have values 1, 2, 3 selected, it will have the hidden value as: `1:2:3`

**What now?**

You then need to turn the colon-delimited string into either a subquery or an expression list, which you can process inside your IN-clause. For example, below I am turning the colon-delimited string into a query.

```sql
select * from table(apex_string.split(:P120_STATE, ':'))
```

From here, I can just include the above in my original query with the IN-clause. For example, *(ignoring your extra page item)*

```
select 
   CITIES.ID as ID, 
   CITIES.NAME as NAME, 
   CITIES.STATE_CODE as STATE_CODE 
from CITIES CITIES where STATE_CODE 
IN ( select * from table(apex_string.split(:P120_STATE, ':')) )
```

**If it's not updating:**

This is a separate issue, but I'll provide a completely working answer. You need a couple of things so that when you change your selection, it updates your other query. Your Dynamic Action (DA) should trigger if the value of `P120_STATE` changes, and in turn set CHECKED_STATES. Note: You may need to do the same for when CHECKED_STATES updates.

Once you make changes to your faceted search (P120_STATE) you need to ADD a DA.

1. Under Dynamic Actions, select Change. Select Item(s). Set `P120_STATE` under Item(s)
2. Under actions, add a TRUE Action that will *Set Value* to your Page Item `CHECKED_STATES`.
3. For your query, you will need to pass `CHECKED_STATES` under *Page Items to Submit*

Comment: Cool! Could you please mark it as the answer then for others to find?